# Аналог justify content : space beetwen для вертикали?

Tags: html, css, css3, flexbox

Вот при justify content space beetwen все элементы гармонично занимают всю ширину, а есть ли тут что то похожее только по вертикали дабы занимали всю высоту

Comment: Я часами сидел искал решение, спасибо огромное за то, что вы есть)

Comment: Пожалуйста, можешь добавить что нравиться вопрос)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть, называется align-content и работает только если включен flex-wrap: wrap;

Answer (score 0):

`align-content: space-between;`. Работает только если включен многострочный режим.

```css
.parent {
  background: pink;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  align-content: space-between;
}

.clildren {
  flex: 0 1 100%;
  color: white;
}

.a {
  background: red;
}

.b {
  background: blue;
}

.c {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="clildren a">A</div>
  <div class="clildren b">B</div>
  <div class="clildren c">C</div>
</div>
```